# Hide remote desktop connection/ Process/ C#

Tags: c#, process, mstsc, remoteapp

Please tell me how to hide the window to connect to the published application via RDP (remote app). Ie when I open rdp file  through the function Process() my process run hidden, but unfortunately this process close  immediately, and run new copy mststc.exe But it state is not hidden :(

```
private const string Arg = "C:\\RDP\\myapp.rdp";
private const string FileName =  "mstsc";
private Process _myProcess = new Process();
...
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sFileName;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcess.Start();

Process mstsc = Process.GetProcessesByName(sFileName)[0];
```

mstsc.Id not equal myProcess.Id

I see that for first time run first copy mstsc.exe (i think processed/parse file), then for second time run ssecond copy mstsc.exe and first copy was killed

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand what you are asking... what is `sFileName` and `arg`? (I am hesitant to make assumptions)

Comment: sorry. sFileName = "mstsc" arg = "C:\\RDP\\myapp.rdp"